# background script spawned by PHP command script print to screen

Tags: php, linux, bash

I need to make a background script that is spawned by PHP command line script that echos to the SSH session. Essentially, I need to do this linux command:

`script/path 2>&1 &`

If I just run this command in linux, it works great. Output is still displayed to the screen, but I can still use the same session for other commands. However, when I do this in PHP, it doesn't work the same way.

I've tried:

`` `script/path 2>&1 &`; ``

`exec("script/path 2>&1 &");`

`system("script/path 2>&1 &")`

...And none of these work. I need it to spawn the process, and then kill itself so that I can free up the session, but I still want the output from the child process to print to the screen.

(please comment if this is unclear... I had a hard time putting this into words :P)

Comment: You might try `shell_exec` instead, that returns the output of a command as a string.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that one, I had forgotten. Unfortunately, it is actually an [alias for using backticks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) in PHP, so I've already tried it.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more detail about your main script. I'm not entirely sure, but I think that your forked process may die if your primary script finishes. 

I'd suggest have the forked process write to a db or a file so that your other process can check the output there.

Comment: @S.Imp I suppose I should mention that if you do `exec("script/path > somefile.log &");`, then the parent script can exit without killing the child, but in this case the output is stored in a file, and not displayed directly to the screen. So I need for the parent script to exit (so that the command prompt comes back) but the child to remain alive, and still output the child's response to the screen. (this is possible in bash, I'm hoping it is possible in PHP.)

Comment: @SkeetsO'Reilly I've written PHP code that forks long-running processes and IIRC, they can be prematurely terminated unless you call posix_setsid to sever their ties to the parent process. The docs on exec also say "If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends." This suggests that you'd need to check the file as I suggested.

Comment: @S.Imp -- thanks, your comment lead me to an answer that will work for me. I just wrote a wrapper bash script that calls the php parent function, and then does a tail on the log for the child function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that works in this case.

I created a wrapper bash script that starts up the PHP script, which in turn spawns a child script that has its output redirected to a file, which the bash script wrapper tails.

Here is the bash script I came up with:

```
  php php_script.php "$@"
  ps -ef | grep php_script.log | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ "$1" != "-stop" ]
  then
      tail -f php_script.log -n 0 &
  fi
```

(it also cleans up "tail" processes that are still running so that you don't get a gazillion processes when you run this bash script multiple times)

And then in your php child script, you call the external script like this:

```
exec("php php_script.php >> php_script.log &");
```

This way the parent PHP script exits without killing the child script, you still get the output from the child script, and your command prompt is still available for other commands.